# Silverlight - Making asynchronous calls in a particular order - CRM

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, dynamics-crm, crm

I am currently using silverlight to build a control for a CRM form.

There are quite a few asynchronous calls being made where I am retrieving various sets
of data. The problem I am facing however is sometimes the calls are made in a random order
and I need to retrieve the data in a particular order for data binding reasons.

Any idea?

Basically I have 3 Methods -

Retrieve Accounts
Retrieve Opporunities
Retrieve Leads

Each have call backs but I want each to respond with results from callback before moving to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make the calls synchronous, or
2. in each call back, invoke the next call